# How do I find companies in my part of the world that still offer a pension?

Tags: united-states, benefits

How can I find a list of companies that currently offer a pension plan?

I would prefer that type of retirement system, instead of one that relies on a 401K.

I would like to be able to search by city/state, but realize that some companies have offices in many locations.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something too narrow in geographic scope.

Comment: I'm sure the federal government has jobs in OK. They still have a pension.

Comment: @JeffO Isn't it a valid question though?  It would be good to have in case someone else wants to know the same thing...

Comment: @Carmine Welcome to the Workplace! The problem with this as currently phrased is for example, let's say Acme Inc has a pension now. Next year, they might not, which will mislead future readers. A more appropriate question for this site would be something along the lines of, "how to determine if a company has a pension plan without interviewing?" or something similar.

Comment: I have an answer, but need to have it reopened to add the answer.

Comment: There is no such thing as security, particularly for something like this.  If you tell a recruiter you're trying to get a job with a pension, they'll figure you're more overhead than asset.

Comment: @Carmine - I voted to reopen, but in the US I think this is going to be limited to some union jobs.

Comment: This question is probably better for [Personal Finance SE](http://money.stackexchange.com)  There are many different types of pension plans besides 401k.

Comment: All American "pension" plans (defined contribution and self-insured count as pensions) are reported annually and filed with the Department of Labor (see "EFAST") and are publicly visible 45 days after filing. Look in the pension benefit code (line 8a on a 5500) for codes starting with "1" for defined benefit plans (traditionally called "pensions") such as "1A" or "1B" (plans with "1H" or "1i" are closed/terminated plans). Codes starting with "2" are defined contribution, such as 401k or 403b plans. The public-facing DOL site isn't searchable geographically, but some other sites are.

Comment: @Chad LOL I posted in Personal Finance SE, and they told me to post here!!

Comment: It is a workplace concern. The decision on which plan is better is a Personal Finance Issue. How to find which company has a particular type of plan is a workplace issue.

Comment: The [Pension Benefit Guaranty Corporation](http://www.pbgc.gov/) which is a federal agency insures defined benefit plans for both [single company](http://search.pbgc.gov/single-employer/) and [multiple company plans](http://search.pbgc.gov/multiemployer/). It has a tool to look them up based on plan name, company, location, and id number.

Comment: I went ahead and reopened after the edits that bring it in-line. Benefits at a job are career-related. If this post starts to go downhill and attract throwaway answers, we can re-close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Pension Benefit Guaranty Corporation](http://www.pbgc.gov/) which is a federal agency insures defined benefit plans for both [single company](http://search.pbgc.gov/single-employer/) and [multiple company plans](http://search.pbgc.gov/multiemployer/). It has a tool to look them up based on plan name, company, location, and id number

Note that this only lists the plans that are insured, but if a company doesn't insure the plan what good is it.

A problem with searching for a company, is that many companies are phasing out the plans. They may prevent new employees from joining the plan, but for existing employees they are still contributing funds. Those plans will still exist for decades, yet no new members will be enrolled.

There are also issues with determining if a large corporation has jobs in your area. They will be listed only at the HQ location for the company or subsidiary.

Comment: A note too regarding companies phasing out these plans, if you are a few years from retirement, keep in mind while you might work for a company which has a defined benefit/pension plan, just because it currently exists does NOT necessarily guarantee it will exist in the same form when we retire. Or even that the company will exist at that time...

Comment: Great answer; I wasn't aware of the PBGC, but that would have made a nice addition to my answer to this question on money.SE.

Comment: When the company goes bankrupt the insurance provided by PBGC makes sure that the plan doesn't disappear. The problem is that there is a maximum amount per year per employee they will pay. If you were expecting more, you will have a problem.